# Bash test command operators

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm just starting out in Bash scripting, and I can't seem to work out what these arguments mean (`-ne` and `-n`). Are they Bash arguments or self created arguments?

```
# Run as root
if [ "$UID" -ne "$ROOT_UID" ]
then
        echo "This must be run as root"
        exit $E_NOTROOT
fi

if [ -n "S1" ]
then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mnemonic for `-ne` is 'not equal'; it does an arithmetic comparison on the two values for inequality.

The mnemonic for `-n` is 'not empty'; it tests whether the argument (`"$1"` in this case) is an empty string.  If `$1` is defined and has a value other than the empty string, the test will be true.

See [Bash conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) for more details.

The `test` command, also known as `[`, supports the other numeric comparison operators too: `-lt` (less than), `-le` (less than or equal to), `-gt` (greater than), `-ge` (greater than or equal to), and `-eq` (equal).  The `-z` operator tests for a zero length string — but note that the argument must be enclosed in double quotes, though (`[ -z "$variable" ]`) as otherwise there is no argument for `-z` to test.

There are many other test operators; this is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

from `man test` :

> **-n STRING**
>
> ```
>      the length of STRING is nonzero
> ```
>
> **INTEGER1 -ne INTEGER2**
>
> ```
>      INTEGER1 is not equal to INTEGER2
> ```